# include php file only at certain screen resolutions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm having issues with adsense on responsive design. One solution I found is to not load them at all if window size is not big enough. So I thought I would create a separate php file with advertisement code, container etc... and than include it on a page. However, I can't figure out how to only include this file if, lets say, window width is 720px or above, else don't include this file.
Perhaps, javascript can be used some way, not sure how it will work with all the dom and php includes though.

Comment: PHP cannot do this alone since it's server side, you're correct in thinking that you'd need to use Javascript. You'd need to pass the resolution through to a PHP file, if you want it to display the advertisements, you could use Ajax to display them based on the callback from the PHP script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
<script language=javascript>
    if (screen.width >= 720 ) 
         $('#place_holder_div').load('file_from_server.php');
</script>
```

Here `#place_holder_div` is a div in your html file. The syntax is `Jquery` but of course you can use plain javascript if you wish. The code looks at the screen width and if greater than 720 pixels, loads the php file `file_from_server.php` (which will contain your ad) into the placeholder div.

Comment: If the adsense works based on impressions and not necessarily only clicks, would you know if google would register this as an impression seeing that the file with the ad was only put there after the actual page has loaded i.e. javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know what the window or screen size of a client is, is by using JavaScript.

```
window.innerHeight; // Available height of the browser for the document
window.innerWidth; // Available width of the browser for the document
window.outerHeight; // Browser height
window.outerWidth; // Browser width
window.screen.height; // Screen height
window.screen.width; // Screen width
```

After inspecting these, you could do a HTTP request for the relevant file. It is, however, probably not the best solution since the user can actually change any size mentioned above at any given time.