# how to execute php file according to screen resolution or size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 php files.

```
include_once('medium.php');
include_once('mobile.php');
```

I want to execute medium.php file when screen size is >992px and mobile.php if screen size is < 992px

What I tried so far is:

```
<script>
var width = $(window).width();
if (width > 992){
</script>   
include_once('medium.php');
<script>} else{</script>
include_once('mobile.php');
<script>}</script>
```

but unable to get the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [include php file only at certain screen resolutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172806/include-php-file-only-at-certain-screen-resolutions)

Comment: this is so wrong, or just for me seems wrong

Comment: better go with ajax requests

Comment: PHP code can't be conditional on Javascript conditions, because PHP runs on the server **before** the page is sent to the client.

Comment: Either send everything to the client and use Javascript to hide and show appropriate elements, or use AJAX to download the appropriate elements dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Go with jquery and ajax `$.load()`function

```
var width = $(window).width();
if (width > 992){
  $( "body" ).load( "medium.php" );
} else{
$( "body" ).load( "mobile.php" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should screen width to PHP file using Ajax or Http.get and let php handle the execution

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['size']) && $_GET['size'] > 992) {
    include_once('medium.php');
} else {
    include_once('mobile.php');
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var script = window.innerWidth > 992 ? "medium.php" : "mobile.php";
var postVars = {} // Use this to provide additional data to you PHP script, or ommit this parameter if you don't need it
var dataType = 'json'; // The type of data your PHP script will return, could be html, json, text. ommit this if you don't have a particular use for it.

jQuery.post(script, postVars, function(response) {
    // This is your callback function, you can do whatever you please with response here.
}, dataType)
</script>
```

**Security notice**
Never trust the end user! As this is client side scripting those variables could manipulated to config.php for instance.

To solve this, you should instead of requesting multiple scripts, request one single script, providing a parameter with a file to include, and then check if that file is allowed to be included.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var script = window.innerWidth > 992 ? "medium.php" : "mobile.php";
var postVars = {file_to_include: script}
var dataType = 'json'; // The type of data your PHP script will return, could be html, json, text. ommit this if you don't have a particular use for it.

jQuery.post("include.php", postVars, function(response) {
    // This is your callback function, you can do whatever you please with response here.
}, dataType)
</script>
```

And then in your PHP script

```
<?php
    if(in_array($_POST["file_to_include"], array("medium.php", "mobile.php"))) {
        include $_POST["file_to_include"];
    }
?>
```